# ios ARKit 3 with iPad Pro 2020, how to use front camera data with back camera tracking?

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, augmented-reality, arkit

The ARKit API supports simultaneous world and face tracking via the back and front cameras, but unfortunately due to hardware limitations, the new iPad Pro 2020 is unable to use this feature (probably because the LIDAR camera takes a lot more power). This is a bit of a step back.

Here is an updated reference in the [example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/combining_user_face-tracking_and_world_tracking):

```
guard ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsUserFaceTracking else {
    fatalError("This sample code requires 
iOS 13 / iPad OS 13, and an iOS device with 
a front TrueDepth camera. Note: 2020 iPads 
do not support user face-tracking while world tracking.")
}
```

There is also a [forum conversation](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/131006) proving that this is an unintentional hardware flaw.

It looks like the mobile technology is not "there yet" for both. However, for my use case I just wanted to be able to switch between front and back tracking modes seamlessly, without needing to reconfigure the tracking space. For example, I would like a button to toggle between "now you track and see my face" mode and "world tracking" mode.

There are 2 cases: it's possible or it's impossible, but maybe there are some alternative approaches depending on that.

Is it possible, or would switching AR tracking modes necessitate setting-up the tracking space again? If so, how would it be achieved?

If it's impossible:
Even if I don't get face-tracking during world-tracking, is there a way to get a front-facing camera feed that I can use with the Vision framework, for example?

Specifically: how do I enable back-facing tracking and get front and back facing camera feeds simultaneously, and disable one or the other selectively? If it's possible even without front-facing tracking and only the basic feed, this will work.

Comment: Apparently you can’t even have multiple AVCaptureSessions running simultaneously. Is this true?